# Laravel ioc automatic resolution - works from controller but not from custom class

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern, ioc-container

Namespaces omitted for brevity...

I have written the following service provider and registered in config/app.php:

```
class OfferServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerLossControlManager();
    }

    protected function registerLossControlManager()
    {
        $this->app->bind('LossControlInterface', 'LossControl');
    }
}
```

Here is my LossControlInterface

```
interface LossControlInterface
{
    /**
     * @param int $demandId
     * @param float $offerTotal
     * @param float $productTotal
     * @param null|int $partnerId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function make($demandId, $offerTotal, $productTotal, $partnerId = null);

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAcceptableLoss();

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAcceptable();

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isUnacceptable();

    /**
     * @return null
     */
    public function reject();
}
```

Now within the controller, I can inject the LossController as follows:

```
use LossControlInterface as LossControl;

class HomeController extends BaseController {
   public function __construct(LossControl $lossControl)
    {
        $this->lossControl = $lossControl;
    }

    public function getLossThresholds()
    {
        $lossControl = $this->lossControl->make(985, 1000, null);

        var_dump('Acceptable Loss: ' . $lossControl->getAcceptableLoss());
        var_dump('Actual Loss: ' . $lossControl->calculateLoss());
        var_dump('Acceptable? ' . $lossControl->isAcceptable());

    }
}
```

However if I try to dependency inject the LossControlInterface from within a custom class called by a command:

```
[2014-09-02 13:09:52] development.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 11 passed to Offer::__construct() must be an instance of LossControlInterface, none given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/.../ProcessOffer.php on line 44 and defined' in /home/vagrant/Code/.../Offer.php:79
```

It appears as though I am unable to dependency inject the interface into a custom class, but I can when dependency injecting into a controller.

Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong or have omitted to get the automatic resolution working?

Comment: can you post the code that is creating the custom class? Is it also created from within a service provider or within your artisan command?

Comment: It is created from within the artisan command. commands/ProcessOffer.php: `private function setOffer(Offer $offer = null) {$this->processOffer    = $offer ?: new Offer();}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IoC is automatic within controllers, and you don't see the injection because Laravel handles the construction of controllers for you.  When creating any other custom class by using the `new` keyword, you will still need to send in all of the parameters needed to it's constructor:

```
$myClass = new ClassWithDependency( app()->make('Dependency') );
```

You can hide this, to a degree, by funneling creation of your custom class through a service provider:

```
// Your service provider
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('ClassWithDependency', function($app) {
        return new ClassWithDependency( $app->make('Dependency') );
    });
}
```

Then just have the IoC make it whenever you need it:

```
$myClass = app()->make('ClassWithDepenency');
```

In your case, you can change your code to look like this:

```
private function setOffer(Offer $offer = null) {
    $this->processOffer    = $offer ?: 
        new Offer( app()->make('LossControlInterface') );
}
```

A perhaps cleaner approach could be to create a service provider and an `OfferFactory` which gets injected into your controller.  The controller can then request the factory to create the offer whenever it needs one:

```
// Controller
public function __construct(OfferFactory $offerFactory)
{
    $this->offerFactory = $offerFactory;
}

public function setOffer(Offer $offer = null)
{
    $this->processOffer = $offer ?: $this->offerFactory->createOffer();
}

// OfferFactory
class OfferFactory
{
    public function createOffer()
    {
        return app()->make('Offer');
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of completely decoupling your controller from the logic behind the creation of the offer, yet allowing you to have a spot to add any amount of complexity necessary to the process of creating offers.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2 the simplest solution for your particular problem would be to replace

```
new Offer();
```

with

```
App::make('Offer');
```

or even shorter

```
app('Offer');
```

which will use Laravel Container to take care of dependencies.

If however you want to pass additional parameters to the `Offer` constructor it is necessary to bind it in your service provider

```
App::bind('Offer', function($app, $args) {
    return new Offer($app->make('LossControl'), $args);
});
```

And voila, now you can write

```
app('Offer', [123, 456]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.4  (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18271) you need to use the new makeWith method of the IoC container.

```
App::makeWith( 'App\MyNameSpace\MyClass', [ $id ] );
```

if you still use 5.3 or below, the above answers will work.