# How to Inject Laravel 5.2 “Illuminate\Http\Request” in your custom classes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and I got a question here. I am trying to inject 'Illuminate\Http\Request' to my custom Class.

`Error: __construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given,`

What is wrong with my code below? Thanks!

```
namespace App\Library;

use Crypt;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MenuAccess
{

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function setLoginSession($user){

       $user = Crypt::encrypt($user);

       $this->request->session()->put('PAZPOSID', $user);

       return $request->session()->pull('PAZPOSID');

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating this MenuAccess class?

Comment: public function test(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($this->menuAccess->setLoginSession('test'));
    }

Comment: I already done this in my controller, so instantiate the class / calling setLoginSession is not a problem. public function __construct()
    {
        $this->menuAccess = new \App\Library\MenuAccess;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error given, you are not passing an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` to your constructor.

Because you type hinted your parameter, PHP will enforce and make sure it's the same type being passed in.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

You can do a `dd($request)` before you instantiate your class to see its type.

If you want Laravel IoC to auto resolve it for you, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623638/laravel-ioc-automatic-resolution-works-from-controller-but-not-from-custom-cla)

Comment: ""Based on the error given, you are not passing an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request to your constructor.""

When I do<br/>
     public function __construct(Request $request){

I got this from Laravel doco, I suspect that 'Illuminate\Http\Request' did not get called properly into my class.

I saw someone answer this, but does not work on mine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307773/injecting-laravel-5-1-illuminate-http-request-in-your-custom-classes

Comment: @JohanSyah I guess you would want Laravel to auto inject the Request for you, right? If so, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

This was an exteremely useful question for me. And the answer is very useful.

Laravel dependency injection seems to work ONLY IN functions and constructors that you don't call by hand (like a constructor of a controller, and a closure (function) that is registered as a route)

Try to call by hand the controller constructor which has a dependency injection, and it will NOT WORK.

Here is an example

In routes.php

```
Route::get('/func_', 'AController@func');

Route::get('/func', function() {
    $c = new App\Http\Controllers\AController;
    return $c->func();
});

Route::get('/f_', 'AController@f');

Route::get('/f', function() {
    $c = new App\Http\Controllers\AController(request());
    return $c->f();
});
```

Add a controller called AController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AController extends Controller
{
    public $req;
    public function __construct(Request $req) {
        $this->req = $req;
    }

    public function func() {
        return $this->req->input('name');
    }

    public function f(Request $r) {
        return $r->input('name');
    }
}
```

And try to run
/func_ will work because the controller will be instantiated by Laravel
/func will NOT work because you tried to call the constructor yourself
/f_ will work because the function which use the dependency injection will be called by Laravel
/f will NOT work although you created the controller correctly. But the function will not work because called by hand without parameters

If you want to call a function which has a dependency injection. Call with full parameters

Comment: Thanks dude! it works, but I found an easier way to do it.. check my own answer below. =) maybe you wanna try too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer. So the problem is in my controller, I need to instantiate in the construct in my controller before I call my custom class.

And I changed nothing in my Custom Class

Here is what I did to fix it:

```
use \App\Library\MenuAccess;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $menuAccess;

    public function __construct(MenuAccess $menuAccess)
    {
        $this->menuAccess = $menuAccess;
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($this->menuAccess->setLoginSession('user@user.com'));
    }
}
```